# Pytest does not rewrite AssertionError

Tags: python, django, pytest, pytest-django

I'm testing a Django project using pytest with the pytest-django and pytest-cov plugins and when I'm telling it to look for tests in a directory (`pytest project -vv --cov --ds=proj.tests`), it does not rewrite the AssertionError when it happens :

```
    def test_pytest():
>      assert 2 == 3
E      AssertionError
```

However, it still always work in another directory / django app, where it is a single tests.py file, as opposed to a directory containing python files in the above case

```
>       assert rec.action == 'updater'
E       assert 'update' == 'updater'
E         - update
E         + updater
E         ?       +
```

Also, I don't know if it helps or just confuse everything, but when looking directly for the file (`pytest project/core/tests/pytest.py -vv --cov --ds=proj.tests`), it works as expected:

```
    def test_pytest():
>       assert 2 == 3
E       assert 2 == 3
```

It's even stranger as it worked before, and I did not touch any of its configuration (everything is the same for my colleague, allegedly he's on a way older commit).

I'm using tox to automate the tests.
Here's the pytest section

```
[pytest]
python_files =
  tests/*.py
  tests*.py
  test_*.py
minversion = 3
```

Why does it not work anymore like it should ? Is there anyway to solve this problem ? I don't want to go back to the days of using print :(

I'm using Python 3.5.2, tox 2.4.1, pytest-django 3.0.0 (and its pytest dep) and pytest-cov 2.4.0

Answer (score 2):

Ok, it was because my files' names in my `tests` directory were not starting with `test_`

Once renamed it worked again

Bug referenced @ [pytest#2121](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/2121)